# Mongoose: is it right to use one connection for every module?

Tags: mongoose

I have a few modules that actually define REST services to mongoDB for different entities.

1) I can create connection in each module
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(mongoURL);

2) I could create one connection outside of modules and then pass it there as a parameter

What is the best approach?

Comment: what do you need the connection for inside the modules? what method do you call on it?

Comment: each module implements RESTful service (CRUD).

Comment: but all you need to implement that are Mongoose-Schemas, not connections, that's why I am asking. I usually just open the connection, then do my `server.listen()`

Comment: in mongoose.model mongoose should be connection object that has active db connection. Besides you may have more then one DB an you need to use createConnection method.